# Batch file to delete ClearCase view-private directories and files

Tags: batch-file, clearcase

After searching on this forum, I finally got down to these 2 command-lines below that I run in a batch file to delete ClearCase view-private directories and files in my snapshot view.

```
REM First delete view-private directories
for /F "usebackq delims=" %%i in (`cleartool ls -r ^| find /V "Rule:" ^| find /V "hijacked" ^| find /V "eclipsed" ^| find /V "-->"`) do ( if exist "%%~i\" ( rmdir /S /Q "%%i" ) )

REM And then delete view-private files
for /F "usebackq delims=" %%i in (`cleartool ls -r ^| find /V "Rule:" ^| find /V "hijacked" ^| find /V "eclipsed" ^| find /V "-->"`) do ( if not exist "%%~i\" ( del /S /Q /F /A:H "%%i" ) )
```

However, I get these errors from time to time:

> Could Not Find C:\Source\Folder\FileA.log
>   Could Not Find C:\Source\Folder\FileB.log
>   Could Not Find C:\Source\Folder\SubFolder\FileC.pbl

The files are view-private files and they do exist at the provided location. But it looks like the batch file cannot "see" to delete them. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If the path longer than 255 characters?

Comment: @VonC No, the longest path is only 144 characters.

Comment: All I can think of is right issue (no read access), or a process which keeps an handle on that file (try the same commands after a full Windows reboot)

Comment: You might be able to detect the issue by using the MS/System Internals Process Monitor tool. Running a procmon trace with the filter set to "Path... begins with ... c:\Source" and starting your script may give ytou some visibility into the issue. If you're actually using a dynamic view, and are on an old ClearCase release, you will want to patch up as procmon can BSOD certain older 7.1.x, 8.0.0, and (IIRC) 8.0.1.0 and 8.0.1.1 versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I updated the delete command to remove the switches and my batch file was finally able to find the view-private files and delete them.

```
REM And then delete view-private files
for /F "usebackq delims=" %%i in (`cleartool ls -r ^| find /V "Rule:" ^| find /V "hijacked" ^| find /V "eclipsed" ^| find /V "-->"`) do ( if not exist "%%~i\" ( del "%%i" ) )
```

Answer (score 0):

Why aren't you using cleartool ls -view_only? It eliminates a lot of the parsing fun here.

Comment: Because it will return checked out files as well, which is not something I want.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't '**cleartool lsprivate -other**' list what you want?

Comment: Peter, lsprivate only works in dynamic views. From the paths @TDN provided, I think we can infer snapshot views.

Comment: @BrianCowan Yes, you are right. I'm doing this in snapshot view. I have edited my question to be more specific.